# Each time I run my code only a few buttons get clicked and then I get hit with a Element Click Intercepted Exception - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, web-scraping

I'm building a scraper with Selenium and have identified a problem that I can't solve.

I want to click on all the 'More' buttons in order to be able to scrape the information in the dropdown.

When I run my code only 2 or 3 near the top get's clicked and then I get hit with an Element Click Intercepted Exception error. I can't see anything covering the other buttons, can it be that Selenium is just running too fast or am I missing something?

Link to the site:
https://www.narpm.org/find/property-managers/?submitted=true&toresults=1&resultsperpage=10&a=managers&orderby=&fname=&lname=&company=&chapter=S005&city=&state=&xRadius=

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =  '/Users/vilje/anaconda3/envs/webscrape/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.narpm.org/find/property-managers/?submitted=true&toresults=1&resultsperpage=10&a=managers&orderby=&fname=&lname=&company=&chapter=S005&city=&state=&xRadius=')


for more in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[contains(@class, 'arrow') and contains(., 'More')]"))):
  more.click()
```

How can I make sure it will click and expand all the buttons and get rid of the element not intercepted exception?

Comment: try to add scrollTo each "more" button inside the loop and make screenshot before click

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The question is, “why is the element not clickable if the element is found?”

This error was because I was using Google Chrome browser, the Chrome driver always clicks in the middle of the element. I switched to Firefox and Geckodriver and now it works.